# How to convert a string to an integer in C++?

Tags: c++, string, integer

Here is my code so far:

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
 string exp;
 cout << "Enter a number and raise it to a power" << endl;
 cin >> exp;
 int num = exp[0];
 int pow = exp[2];

 cin.get();
 cin.ignore(256,'\n');
 }
```

Basically, I'm trying to make a program where you can enter something like "2^5" and it will solve it for you. So far, I have taken the first and third values of the string and called them "num" and "pow". (Number, Power) If you try something like "cout << num;" it will give you the decimal Ascii value. How do I convert it to a decimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int num;
    char op;
    int pow;
    if ((std::cin >> num >> op >> pow) && op == '^') {
            // do anything with num and pow
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can read from `cin` directly to integer variables:

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;
```

but you cannot enter naturally looking expressions that way.

To read `2^5` you can use `std::stringstream`:

```
int pos = exp.find('^');
int n;
std::stringstream ss;
if(pos != std::npos){
    ss << exp.substr(0, pos);
    ss >> n;
}
```

and similar for the second variable.

This method is implemented in Boost as `boost::lexical_cast`.

More complicated expressions require building a parser and I suggest, that you read more about this subject.

Comment: or use the `std::stoi()` function: `n = std::stoi(exp.substr(0,pos));`

Answer (score 2):

[`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) is very good at this.  It reads as many numeric digits as possible, returns the number, and also gives you a pointer to the character that caused it to stop (in your case that would be the `'^'`).

Comment: @Alcott: `atoi` only gives you the first two, no error reporting whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all your numbers are inferior to 10, in this case `exp[0]-'0'` and `exp[1]-'0'` are enough.